# Vreate two timepicker, one for minutes and one for hours

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I want to create two timepickers to calculate starttime, one for minutes and one for hours separately. Here is my code:

```
<span class="value">
    @Html.Telerik().TimePickerFor(m => m.StartTime).InputHtmlAttributes(new { @readonly = true })
    <br>
</span>
```

Comment: Well, why not have 2 dropdowns or numeric input (1-60 and 1-24)? Timepicker just abstract this away into a single component.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt actually that what I need but I don't know how to do that. I mean how to attach them to the same input field(start time). if u could help I will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for the modern component type `ComponentType("modern")`.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
    .Name("timepicker")
    .Value("10:00 AM")
    .ComponentType("modern")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%", title = "timepicker" })
    .DateInput()
)
```

Here is a demo:
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/timepicker/component-type